# Pycharm - Unsaved File for general use

Tags: pycharm

In Pycharm is there a way to have unsaved open file to use as a 'play area' to copy and paste, compare lines, etc in a similar way to how new tabs work in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure there is nothing exactly like that.  But for my purposes I keep a junk.py file for exactly this reason and have my git projects ignore it specifically.  This way it doesn't impact any of my projects and is always there as a scratch pad

Comment: AW that's a shame. I think I'll just keep Sublime in another desktop for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scratch pad under Tools | New Scratch File .
This file is not added to any git repository.